# Autoform editing profiles

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using aldeed:autoform

I have these Schemas

```
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
fullName: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
},
bio: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
}
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
username: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
},
emails: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true
},
"emails.$": {
    type: Object
},
"emails.$.address": {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
},
"emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date
},
profile: {
    type: Schema.UserProfile,
    optional: true
},
services: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true
}
});
```

and I got this template

```
<template name="editProfile">
    {{#autoForm collection="Meteor.users" doc=userdoc id="updateUser" type="update"}}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Profile Page</legend>
        <div id="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='username'}} has-error{{/if}}">
            {{> afQuickField name='username'}}
        </div>
        <div id="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='emails.0.address'}} has-error{{/if}}">
            {{> afQuickField name='emails.0.address'}}
        </div>
        <div id="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='profile.firstName'}} has-error{{/if}}">
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.firstName'}}
        </div>
        <div id="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='profile.bio'}} has-error{{/if}}">
            {{> afQuickField name='profile.bio'}}
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
{{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

My `editProfile.js` provides a helper:

```
 Template.hello.helpers({
     userdoc: function() {
         return Meteor.user()
     }
 });
```

I can't update the fields when the autoform field for `emails.0.address` is present. Including this breaks my entire form (I cannot update anything) and I wonder why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your helper in `editProfile.js` should be for the "editProfile" template, not "hello" template.

```
Template.editProfile.helpers({
     userdoc: function() {
         return Meteor.user();
     }
 });
```

but you could also use `currentUser` in your template since this is a global helper

```
{{#autoForm collection="Meteor.users" doc=currentUser id="updateUser" type="update"}}
```